# Android Application Internet Access Behind Proxy

Tags: android, proxy, android-emulator

I have an android application(Android 2.2) accessing internet behind proxy.

I have tried setting an APN with proxy host & port and it works fine in emulator browser. 
But the application fails to connect to internet.

I have also tried command line option of -http-proxy, it doesn't work.

Can somebody help me with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so many days of struggling, I found out there is an issue on android when accessing the https using apache HTTP client with proxy.

Refer this for issue.http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2690

The fix for the problem is [here](https://review.source.android.com/#change,15755).

Answer (score 0):

set Permission for your APP to access the Internet on your Manifest File.like..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

For More Info check the ApiDemos APP and [thes](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html)e [Documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-permission-element.html)

Comment: if for any reason that doesn't fix it, look in logcat and find out what the actual error is

Comment: I have set the internet permissions. Logcat is not displaying any error. The webview fails to load the url. It displays following:The web page at <url> might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address. I tried with multiple url's but result is same.

Comment: After some tries of debugging, logcat shows that "www.google.com:Host is unresolved." Seems DNS issue. Then I tried with IP address but it then gives security exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
String myProxy=Proxy.getDefaultHost() ;
        int myPort=Proxy.getDefaultPort();
        HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost(myProxy,myPort,"http");
        client.getParams().setParameter (ConnRoutePNames.DEFAULT_PROXY, proxy);
```

try giving this within your java file. before that change your proxy settings in emulator!